# Index data from not related models in Django-Haystack Solr

Tags: python, django, solr

I have a model to which multiple other models point through foreign keys, like:

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

class PointingModel1(models.Model):
    color=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    main_model=models.ForeignKey(MainModel)

class PointingModel2(models.Model):
    othername=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    main_model=models.ForeignKey(MainModel)
```

So I want to return the name of the MainModel by searching for color and othername fields in the PointingModels. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is DyndbComplexExp? share code of DyndbComplexExp model.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the copy pasting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy.

```
colors = PointingModel1.objects.filter(color='blue')
for color in colors:
    name = color.main_model.name
    # now you can put `name` to a list or something else
```

Comment: Should this go in views.py?

Comment: If you need `name` in views, then in views. Actually, this can live anywhere in your project where you need this data.